# How do I set a breakpoint for when a vector<int> increases in length?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, vector, breakpoints

I have a vector that is empty, something is filling it somewhere and I cant find it.  I want to set a memory breakpoint so that when the push_back occurs the program will break.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and the problem is that the vector doesnt display its internal members in the watch window (it seems to have a custom formatting).  It just looks like this:

myVector[0]()          std::vector< int,std::allocator< int > >

Indicating size 0.  Any tips?

Comment: Why not set a breakpoint on push_back?

Comment: Thats not bad, but wouldnt catch other cases like resize, assignment, etc.  But thanks!

Comment: A vector has no virtual functions, and it only has three members. One is a pointer, one is the allocation size, and one is the number of elements actually in the vector. Without knowing the actual class layout (though you could just look it up in the <vector> header), it should not be hard to find by trial and error which memory address to watch (very likely `vec+ sizeof(void*)`)

Comment: If you add '!' modifier in the watch window, custom visualizers won't be used and you'll see the raw members of whatever variable. Add `myVector,!` instead of `myVector` to the watch window, and voilà.

Comment: Did not know about the '!' trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is for VS 2010 - details might differ in other versions.

Since the debugger uses a data visualizer (or whatever it's called) to display the state of a `std::vector`, you have to look in the `<vector>` header to determine the names of the actual members of the class and which one(s) might be responsible for tracking the number of elements. An easy way to do this is to step through a call to `vector::push_back()`.

In VC++ 2010 this is a member pointer named `_Mylast`.

So all you have to do is set a data breakpoint on writes to `&v._Mylast` (where `v` is the vector you are interested in debugging).

The next time an element is added, the debugger will break with a call stack showing exactly where.

Comment: You need to input  "v._Mypair._Myval2._Mylast" in VS2019 on Windows 10

Comment: Can VS remember the string of the data breakpoint like "v._Mypair._Myval2._Mylast"? It seems to only remember the calculated address and you need to delete old/add new in each debug session which is a nightmare....

Answer (score 0):

It shows 0 in VC2010, [0] indicates the size of the vector and the items will be displayed in ().
and you can use memory output windows to find out the memory address.